# Trouble getting an address from _dyld_get_image_header method in iOS program

Tags: objective-c, cydia-substrate

**_ dyld _ get _ image _ vmaddr _ slide** and **_ dyld _ get _ image _ header** method return nothing

I am trying to call a function using dynamic library in IOS program with ill2cpp engine

To do this, I need to add the address of the function from the disassembled UnityFramework code (ill2cpp) with the address at which this library was loaded into the program memory

I use the image list command for the LLDB debugger and find the index at which the library was loaded:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ErIW.png)

The index turned out to be 488 (already taking into account my additional library)

I wrote the following code to get the address where the library was loaded (this address can be seen in the photo, after the index and identifier):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>


static bool (*in_Room)();

%ctor {

    const struct mach_header* header = _dyld_get_image_header(488); // 448 is index of library

    uintptr_t global_addr = (uintptr_t)header;

    uintptr_t EXEC_ADDR1 = global_addr + 0x1b27cdc;

    in_Room = (bool(*)())EXEC_ADDR1;


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        while(1)
        {
            sleep(20);
            in_Room(); // function call
        }
        
    });
}
```

But this did not help in any way: the **_ dyld _ get _ image _ header** method did not return anything, and therefore the clean address from the disassembler was called:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgCaS.png)

The debugger showed that there was an attempt to access a non-existent address in the program memory, that is, to the address 0x1b27cdc, because the **_dyld _ get _ image _ header** method did not return anything

Why didn't the method return anything? How can I get the address of the library?

I will be glad for any help!